# Akka.net .net standard to .net core thought Receptionist

Tags: c#, .net-core, protobuf-net, akka.net, .net-4.7

I go my main Akka.net (1.3.6) code stored into .net standard libraries 2.0.

I use this common code in a light house in .net Core 2.0 connect to all my processing agent in .net core 2.0 too.

This part correctly connect together and work fine.

To send processing command to my cluster i use the ClusterClientReceptionist pattern.

One of the Cluster client is a WCF hosted in a Windows Console applications (.net 4.7).
When this app try to connect to the cluster thought a ClusterClientReceptionist i get a Protobuf exception "Method Not Found"

[image]

I tryed to changed serializer from **Hyperion** (1.3.6-beta62 also tryed previous versions) to classic NewtownJson serializer, but no changes.

I read on guthub that theire is issue between cross-platform communication.

Is there a temporary solution available ?
Does i need to create a specific serialize that doesn't use Protobuf ?

Comment: It looks like a problem with version of [DotNetty](https://github.com/Azure/DotNetty) library, one of the Akka.NET dependencies.

Comment: I use the lastest version of DotNetty (0.4.7) and ProtoBuf ask (3.5.1).

Comment: Version 0.4.8 of DotNetty launch today seems to correct the bug ^^